# How can I setup Excel to round down from .90 and round up from .91. IE; 5.90 needs to show up as 5 and 5.91 needs to show 6. Thank you

Tags: excel

How can I setup Excel to round down from .90 and round up from .91.  IE; 5.90 needs to show up as 5 and 5.91 needs to show 6.  Can this be done in Excel?

Comment: `=IF(A1-TRUNC(A1) > 0.9,ROUNDUP(A1,0),ROUNDDOWN(A1,0))`?

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!

Comment: `=INT(G12+0.0999999999)`